# Android Studio is not recognizing Keystore alias while generating signed apk

Tags: java, android, apk, keystore, android-studio-3.0

I am getting this error everytime I tried to generate my signed apk through Android Studio:

**No key with alias 'Operator_keystore' found in keystore PATH/OrderOperator_keystore**

Previously I successfully submitted builts with the same keystore. The problem arises when I move my whole project folder to another folder, also I invalidated the cache of android studio.

I am signing apk like this
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and run the following command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore </path/to/your/keystore.jks>
```

After you enter the keystore password, it will display the list of certificates stored in that keystore, including the alias names, e.g.

```
Keystore type: jks
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: Nov 19, 2018
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
...
```

Look at the **alias name** displayed, and compare that with the value you put in the **Key alias** field in that Studio window.

Comment: Somebody not copying and Paste the phonegap texts at long last! THANKS!
In my case, the program was adding a character to my alias name because a tiny mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you key store path is correct with the location of the new folder and also make sure you're entering the correct password for both key store and alias. If that doesn't work try changing
    keystore PATH/OrderOperator_keystore
To
    keystore PATH/

**There shouldn't be any space between keystone Path also**

Comment: I am choosing my keystore file by Choose existing button. so paths are correct, also Alias is correct.

Comment: Please synching project with gradle files then to adopt all changes if any

Comment: My project is running fine in debug mode, also i clean and rebuild project.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Gradle into signingReport and generate a hash key or sha1 key  and also refresh the app level build.gradle file after submitting the form for keystore